# 'KMeansModel' object has no attribute 'computeCost' in apache pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm experimenting with a clustering model in pyspark. I'm trying to get the mean squared cost of the cluster fit for different values of K

```
def meanScore(k,df):
  inputCol = df.columns[:38]
  assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=inputCols,outputCol="features")
  kmeans = KMeans().setK(k)
  pipeModel2 = Pipeline(stages=[assembler,kmeans])
  kmeansModel = pipeModel2.fit(df).stages[-1]
  kmeansModel.computeCost(assembler.transform(df))/data.count()
```

When I try to call this function to compute costs for different values of K in the dataframe

```
for k in range(20,100,20):
  sc = meanScore(k,numericOnly)
  print((k,sc))
```

I receive an attribute error as
**AttributeError: 'KMeansModel' object has no attribute 'computeCost'**

I'm fairly new to pyspark and am just learning, I sincerely appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Comment: it means this computeCost method does not exist. check the docs for correct usage. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is deprecated in Spark 3.0.0 [Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.evaluation.ClusteringEvaluator) suggest using the evaluator.

```
Note Deprecated in 3.0.0. It will be removed in future versions. 
Use ClusteringEvaluator instead. You can also get the cost on the training dataset in the summary.
```

Answer (score 7):

As Erkan sirin mentioned computeCost is deprecated in recent version this may help you solve your problem

```
# Make predictions 
predictions = model.transform(dataset)
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import ClusteringEvaluator
# Evaluate clustering by computing Silhouette score
evaluator = ClusteringEvaluator()
silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Silhouette with squared euclidean distance = " + str(silhouette))
```

I hope this helps, you can check official docs for more informations

Answer (score 1):

As for the current version [3.1.2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html#k-means).

Using KMeans as example, after importing

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import ClusteringEvaluator
```

Loading data and training, then it's just call **'ClusteringEvaluator()'**:

```
# Make predictions
predictions = model.transform(dataset)

# Evaluate clustering by computing Silhouette score
evaluator = ClusteringEvaluator()

silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Silhouette with squared euclidean distance = " + str(silhouette))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Evaluate clustering by computing Silhouette score:

in Spark 3.0.1 and above

```py
print('Silhouette with squared euclidean distance:')
pdt = model.transform(final_data)
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import ClusteringEvaluator
evaluator = ClusteringEvaluator()
silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(pdt)
print(silhouette)
```

### Evaluate clustering With in set sum of squre errors(wssse):

spark 2.2 to 3.0.0

```py
cost = model.computeCost(dataset)
print("Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = " + str(cost))
```

Answer (score 0):

For KMeans instead of "computeCost" you can use also:

```
wssse = kmeansModel.summary.trainingCost
```