# AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'setK'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Example from https://runawayhorse001.github.io/LearningApacheSpark/clustering.html
caused strange error while I decided to test the clustering example for Spark.
Example:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

import numpy as np

cost = np.zeros(20)

for k in range(2,20):
    kmeans = KMeans()\
            .setK(k)\
            .setSeed(1) \
            .setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures")\
            .setPredictionCol("cluster")
model = kmeans.fit(data)
cost[k] = model.computeCost(data)
```

And it caused Error in Kmeans attributes despite of fit already implemented.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-296a7d54514a> in <module>
      2 cost = np.zeros(20)
      3 for k in range(2,20):
----> 4     kmeans = KMeans()\
      5             .setK(k)\
      6             .setSeed(1) \

AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'setK'
```

I had similar issues in the past and `.fit()` solved them, but now it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You're importing the wrong KMeans. I believe that KMeans refer to the one in Spark ML, not in scikit-learn.

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
```

Comment: Everyting just the same.

Comment: @Alexey_ (1) did you remove the line that imports scikit-learn? (2) can you show the output of `print(KMeans)`?

Comment: computeCost is deprecated, as discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65195312/kmeansmodel-object-has-no-attribute-computecost-in-apache-pyspark). The tutorial you're following is outdated I think @Alexey_